# Postgres - Aggregation throws error when joining more than 2 tables

Tags: postgresql

I have a few tables and wanted to retrieve results from all tables

1. event
2. slot_archive
3. event_meta
4. booking

**Tables details:**

```
CREATE TABLE event(
id integer,
url text,
name text, 
event_start  date, 
event_end   date,
sub_type text
);

CREATE TABLE slot_archive(
id integer,
event_id integer,
date text,
start_time  text, 
end_time   text,
current_registration integer, 
location_id integer
);

CREATE TABLE event_meta(
id integer,
event_id integer,
data json
);

CREATE TABLE booking(
id integer,
event_id integer,
data json
);
```

**Query without joining the booking table. And this works fine:**

```
select COALESCE((meta.data ->> 'walkins')::int, 0) as walkins, 
COALESCE((meta.data ->> 'attendanceSubmitted')::boolean, false) as "attendanceSubmitted", meta.data -> 'heroImage' as "heroImage", 
meta.data -> 'tileContent' -> 'registrationPage' ->> 'title' as title, 
evnt.id as "eventId", 
evnt.url as "eventUrl", 
evnt.name as name, 
evnt.event_start AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as "startTime", 
evnt.event_end AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as "endTime", 
evnt.sub_type as type, 
agg_slot.slotDates as slots, 
agg_slot.registrationcount as "registrationCount" 
from event as evnt inner join event_meta meta on evnt.id = meta.event_id, 
(select event_id, location_id, array_agg(CONCAT_WS(' ', slot.date,slot.start_time,slot.end_time)) as slotDates, sum(current_registration) as registrationCount from slot_archive as slot 
group by slot.event_id, slot.location_id) as agg_slot 
where evnt.id = agg_slot.event_id 
and evnt.id in (select id from event where event_end + interval '48h' < now()) 
and agg_slot.location_id = 'location id goes here';
```

**Query with joining the booking table. And this throws error:**

I'm trying to find out the sum of `attendeeCount` from the booking table, hence joining the table

```
select COALESCE(sum((b.data ->> 'attendanceCount')::int),0), 
COALESCE((meta.data ->> 'walkins')::int, 0) as walkins, 
COALESCE((meta.data ->> 'attendanceSubmitted')::boolean, false) as "attendanceSubmitted", meta.data -> 'heroImage' as "heroImage", 
meta.data -> 'tileContent' -> 'registrationPage' ->> 'title' as title, 
evnt.id as "eventId", 
evnt.url as "eventUrl", 
evnt.name as name, 
evnt.event_start AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as "startTime" , 
evnt.event_end AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as "endTime", 
evnt.sub_type as type, 
agg_slot.slotDates as slots, 
agg_slot.registrationcount as "registrationCount" from event as evnt 
inner join event_meta meta on evnt.id = meta.event_id 
inner join booking b on evnt.id = b.event_id, 
(select event_id, 
location_id, 
array_agg(CONCAT_WS(' ', slot.date,slot.start_time,slot.end_time)) as slotDates, sum(current_registration) as registrationCount 
from slot_archive as slot 
group by slot.event_id, slot.location_id) as agg_slot 
where evnt.id = agg_slot.event_id and evnt.id in (select id from event where event_end + interval '48h' < now()) 
and agg_slot.location_id = 'location id goes here';
```

**Error : column "meta.data" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function**

[DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4FA6eCZnHJ6Eb7LZ5Nu41m/8) for reference

Appreciate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want attendeeCount from booking table you can use it as subquery same as slot_archive

Try this :

```
select  attendeeCount,
COALESCE((meta.data ->> 'walkins')::int, 0) as walkins,
COALESCE((meta.data ->> 'attendanceSubmitted')::boolean, false)
as "attendanceSubmitted", meta.data -> 'heroImage' as "heroImage"
, meta.data -> 'tileContent' -> 'registrationPage' ->> 'title' as title,
evnt.id as "eventId", evnt.url as "eventUrl", evnt.name as name,
evnt.event_start AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as "startTime" ,
evnt.event_end AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as "endTime", 
evnt.sub_type as type, agg_slot.slotDates as slots, 
agg_slot.registrationcount as "registrationCount" from event as evnt 
inner join event_meta meta on evnt.id = meta.event_id inner join
(select event_id,COALESCE(sum((data ->> 'attendeeCount')::int),0) as attendeeCount from 
booking  group by event_id) b on evnt.id = b.event_id, (select event_id, location_id,
array_agg(CONCAT_WS(' ', slot.date,slot.start_time,slot.end_time)) as 
slotDates, sum(current_registration) as registrationCount from
slot_archive as slot group by slot.event_id, slot.location_id) 
as agg_slot where evnt.id = agg_slot.event_id and evnt.id in
(select id from event where event_end + interval '48h' < now()) 
and agg_slot.location_id = '3350';
```